# How can I inject custom provider used in another provider in nest js testing module

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using nestjs and typeorm.
I've created `RepositoryFactory` which gives me correct entity based on Region value.

```js
export const REPOSITORY_PROVIDER = 'REPOSITORY_PROVIDER'

export const RepositoryFactory = {
  provide: REPOSITORY_PROVIDER,
  useFactory:
    (entityManager: EntityManager) =>
    (region: Region): Repository<EntityInstance> => {
      switch (region) {
        case Region.EU:
          return entityManager.getRepository(Entity)
        case Region.AP:
          return entityManager.getRepository(APEntity)
        case Region.US:
          return entityManager.getRepository(USEntity)
        default:
          throw new Error(`Invalid region name: ${region}`)
      }
    },
  inject: [EntityManager]
}
```

I'm using it in my `MainServiceProvider`

```js
export class MainServiceProvider {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REPOSITORY_PROVIDER)
    private getRepository: (region: Region) => Repository<EntityInstance>
  ) {}

 async createRequest() {...}
}
```

How can inject `RepositoryFactory` in test cases for `MainServiceProvider`?

I tried to add it simply like below but this is not the correct way. I need to test if region is correctly provided.

```js
 {
   provide: REPOSITORY_PROVIDER,
   useValue: {save: jest.fn(), findOne: jest.fn()}
 }
```